# Remove elements by value satisfying certain condition

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures

From these data structures, I want to remove elements by value, that satisfies certain condition

```
<Data Structures>

 - RowSortedTable<String, String, Double> a;     (Guava Table)
 - HashMap<String, Double> b;
```

From the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594059/removing-all-items-of-a-given-value-from-a-hashmap), I found the elegant answer using `Collections.Singleton` however, it seems like exact matching is required.

```
hmap.values().removeAll(Collections.singleton("Two"));
```

Here, I want to remove elements from a table or map where their values are smaller than certain threshold. What would be your way to write the code?

---

I just checked two answers and those are answers about map, how about the table case? My solution is as follows.

```
for (Iterator<String> it1 = proptypeconf.columnKeySet().iterator(); it1.hasNext();) {
        String type = it1.next();
        System.out.println(type);
        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Double>> it2 = proptypeconf.column(type).entrySet().iterator(); it2.hasNext();){
            Map.Entry<String, Double> e = it2.next();
            if (e.getValue() < conflist.get(index-1)) {
                it2.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Table` is no different at all.  Just use `table.values()` the same as for maps.  You can use exactly the same code.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thank you! Just checked out tables work exactly the same. I was trying to solve a problem the hard way ... :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = hmap.values().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  if (iterator.next() < threshold) {
     iterator.remove();
  }
}
```

Of course, if you're on Java 8, it's much easier:

```
hmap.values().removeIf(value -> value < threshold);
```

Tables work exactly the same; just use `table.values()` instead of `hmap.values()`.