# Remove all entries from HashMap where value is NOT what I'm looking for

Tags: java, hashmap

The title question summarizes it nicely, but assume I am coding in Java and have a `HashMap` that looks something like this (it has a lot more entries obviously):

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();

myMap.put{"a", 1}
myMap.put{"b", 2}
myMap.put{"c", 2}
myMap.put{"d", 3}
```

Now I don't like entries with the value of 2, so I want to remove them ***all*** as effectively as possible, leaving me only with the entries that have value 1 or 3.

It should look as if my map was instead made like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();

myMap.put{"a", 1}
myMap.put{"d", 3}
```

As if my 2-valued entries were never there at all!

What are my options for doing this in an effective way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing all items of a given value from a hashmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594059/removing-all-items-of-a-given-value-from-a-hashmap)

Comment: Is it just me or is the header describes the opposite requirement?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
map.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getValue() == 2)
```

Comment: This did it! I had to go with `map.entrySet().removeIf(e -> (int) ((Entry) e).getValue() == 2)` but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 1):

### Using helper map

If you want to do it as effectively as possible you can create an inverted map:

```
HashMap<Integer, List<String>> affectedKeysMap = new HashMap<>();
```

You'll need to track **all updates** to both maps manually to keep them in sync.

This will allow you to find and remove affected keys in an effective way:

```
int valueToRemove = 2;
for(String affectedKey : affectedKeysMap.get(2)) {
    map.remove(affectedKey);
}
affectedKeysMap.remove(valueToRemove);
```

### Using single map

With a single `HashMap` all you can do is traverse the whole set of entries because `HashMap` doesn't support fast search by value.

This question already covers different approaches with a single map: [Removing all items of a given value from a hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594059/removing-all-items-of-a-given-value-from-a-hashmap)

### Using something else

Another option is to look for a specialized collection class that supports bidirectional search and removal. Check out these discussions for possible leads:

- [Bidirectional multi-valued map in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066109/bidirectional-multi-valued-map-in-java)
- [Do we have a MultiBiMap ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390923/do-we-have-a-multibimap)

Comment: Great answer, but sadly not the first one to it. This gave me plenty of reading though, so a juicy vote-up for you!

Answer (score 0):

Using [guava](https://github.com/google/guava) you could do it like this:

```
Integer valueToDrop = Integer.valueOf(2);
Predicate<Integer> predicate = Predicates.not(Predicates.equalTo(valueToDrop));
Map<String, Integer> filteredMap = Maps.filterValues(myMap, predicate);
```